# Remove White Space between Blocks

Tags: html, email, newsletter, email-templates

I don't really know how to code and I tried looking up the answer but I get lost. Can someone help me figure out how to remove all this white space? It's for an email newsletter. Thanks!I need the white space removed before and after each block. When I go to send the email it's too long and gets clipped so I'm trying to avoid that. thanks so much!

```html
  <!-- SECTION - ROI -->
    <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:450px;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                    <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:42px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                                                    {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %}
                                                                        {% widget_attribute "html" %}
                                                                            <h4 style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:23px;font-weight:700;line-height:28px;margin:-30px -0 20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">Our Product in Motion.</h4>
                                                                            <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:20px;padding: 10;text-align:left">Text placeholder for Dole information - this is placeholder text and will add more later.</p>
                                                                            <a href="#" style="Margin:0;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                                                                        {% end_widget_attribute %}
                                                                    {% end_widget_block %}
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                                <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:16px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding-top:-10px;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:-30px 20px -20px;">
                                                                    <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='http://34ueos46m798gtit1j06461b.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Demo_slide_v2.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:300px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
       <!-- SECTION - VERGE -->
    <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:450px;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                    <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:12px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                                                    {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %}
                                                                        {% widget_attribute "html" %}
                                                                            <h4 style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:23px;font-weight:700;line-height:28px;margin:15px 0 20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">Placeholder</h4>
                                                                            <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left">Placeholder Text.</p>
                                                                            <a href="#" style="Margin:0;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                                                                        {% end_widget_attribute %}
                                                                    {% end_widget_block %}
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                                <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:-50px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:0px 20px 0px;">
                                                                    <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (300px/340px)', src='https://elementalexcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/IMG_9526.jpg', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:250px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Which application are you using for this? Dreamweaver (Windows) lets you do it with `shift + tab`. There are ways to do it on other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an [HTML minifier.](https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/) A minifier maintains the same functionality by reducing the file size of your code.

Comment: Pretty neat tool - I'll play around with it some. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned height of table `450px`. removing height css or setting it to `auto` can solve your problem.

```html
<!-- SECTION - ROI -->
    <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                    <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:42px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                                                    {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %}
                                                                        {% widget_attribute "html" %}
                                                                            <h4 style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:23px;font-weight:700;line-height:28px;margin:-30px -0 20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">Our Product in Motion.</h4>
                                                                            <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:20px;padding: 10;text-align:left">Text placeholder for Dole information - this is placeholder text and will add more later.</p>
                                                                            <a href="#" style="Margin:0;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                                                                        {% end_widget_attribute %}
                                                                    {% end_widget_block %}
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                                <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:16px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding-top:-10px;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:-30px 20px -20px;">
                                                                    <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='http://34ueos46m798gtit1j06461b.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Demo_slide_v2.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:300px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
       <!-- SECTION - VERGE -->
    <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                    <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:12px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                                                    {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %}
                                                                        {% widget_attribute "html" %}
                                                                            <h4 style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:23px;font-weight:700;line-height:28px;margin:15px 0 20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">Placeholder</h4>
                                                                            <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left">Placeholder Text.</p>
                                                                            <a href="#" style="Margin:0;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                                                                        {% end_widget_attribute %}
                                                                    {% end_widget_block %}
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                                <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:0.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:-50px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;">
                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:0px 20px 0px;">
                                                                    <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (300px/340px)', src='https://elementalexcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/IMG_9526.jpg', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:250px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```